# what is the correct way to access this multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php

I cannot seem to find the correct way to access the VAT value of this array...

```
$freeholdPurchases = array(
            'up to £150,000' => array('costs' => '£620.83', 'VAT' => '£124.17' , 'Total' => '£745.00'),
            '£150,000 - £200,000' => array('costs' => '£620.83', 'VAT' => '£124.17', 'Total' => '£745.00'),
            '£200,001 - £250,000' => array('costs' => '£700.00', 'VAT' => '£140.00', 'Total' => '£840.00'),
            '£250,001 - £300,000' => array('costs' => '£741.67', 'VAT' => '£148.33', 'Total' => '£890.00'),
            '£300,001 - £400,000' => array('costs' => '£783.33', 'VAT' => '£156.67', 'Total' => '£940.00'),
            '£400,001 - £500,000' => array('costs' => '£825.00', 'VAT' => '£165.00', 'Total' => '£990.00'),
            '£500,001 - £600,000' => array('costs' => '£866.67', 'VAT' => '£173.33', 'Total' => '£1,040.00'),
            '£600,001 to £700,000' => array('costs' => '£908.33', 'VAT' => '£181.67', 'Total' => '£1,090.00'),
            '£700,001 - £800,000' => array('costs' => '£950.00', 'VAT' => '£190.00', 'Total' => '£1,140.00'),
            '£800,001 - £900,000' => array('costs' => '£991.67', 'VAT' => '£198.33', 'Total' => '£1,190.00'),
            '£900,001 to £1,000,000' => array('costs' => '£1,033.33', 'VAT' => '£206.67', 'Total' => '£1,240.00')
    );
```

In my limited knowledge i've tried:

```
 $freeholdPurchases['up to £150,000'][1][0]
```

and lots of variations of this but cant seem to figure it out

can anyone help me understand the syntax i need to access it or if i need to change my array at all.

Thanks

Comment: $freeholdPurchases['up to £150,000']['VAT'] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was to access the VAT value of this array. You will get VAT with the value of £ 148.33 with

```
$vat148p33 = $freeholdPurchases['£250,001 - £300,000']['VAT'];
```

All values and the area:

```
foreach($freeholdPurchases as $area => $row){
  echo 'Area: '.$area.' VAT:'.$row['VAT'].'<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
Area: up to £150,000 VAT:£124.17
Area: £150,000 - £200,000 VAT:£124.17
Area: £200,001 - £250,000 VAT:£140.00
Area: £250,001 - £300,000 VAT:£148.33
Area: £300,001 - £400,000 VAT:£156.67
Area: £400,001 - £500,000 VAT:£165.00
Area: £500,001 - £600,000 VAT:£173.33
Area: £600,001 to £700,000 VAT:£181.67
Area: £700,001 - £800,000 VAT:£190.00
Area: £800,001 - £900,000 VAT:£198.33
Area: £900,001 to £1,000,000 VAT:£206.67
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```php
$freeholdPurchases['up to £150,000']['Total'];
```

You have defined `$freeholdPurchases['up to £150,000']` as a tagged (associative) array whose elements have names (tags) so you access its elements by tag name. The same is true for `$freeholdPurchases`.

Answer (score 0):

Associative array contains keys and values.
Syntax understanding:

```php
$data = array(
  'country' => array(
    'company' => array (
      'director' => array(
        'first_name' => 'Bill',
        'last_name' => 'Gates',
      )
    )
  )
)

$director = $data['country']['company']['director'];
$director_full_name = $director['first_name'] . ' ' . $director['last_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly:

**$freeholdPurchases['£250,001 - £300,000']['VAT']**

and all the explanations were very helpful too.